# Formatting a USB stick - unable to operate USB

Tags: usb

I followed this commandline method([described in here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198065/how-to-format-a-usb-drive)) — since ubuntu studio was different from original ubuntu, and the options were not available in GUI version —to format a USB stick, but I hadn't read after the part that required me to wait, and as a result my USB stick doesn't operate now. However, when I do plug it in, `lsblk`, shows that my USB is connect, however it's inoperable.

How can i recover my USB stick?

Comment: try using `fdisk` as shown in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/558412/1041631)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a tool with a graphical user interface, that can help you perform the task to restore a USB stick to a standard storage device, **[mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)**.

- mkusb 'wraps a safety belt around `dd`', helps you to identify and select the correct target device (the correct USB stick and not another device).
- The standard storage device has an MSDOS partition table and a partition with the FAT32 file system.
- If you want another file system, you can use mkusb to wipe the first mibibyte and after that use **gparted** to create the file system.

You find details how to install and use mkusb at the following links,

- [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)
- [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe)

[image]

If mkusb cannot solve the problem at once, you may find a solution or at least an explanation (if the USB stick itself is read-only or completely 'bricked') via the following link,

[Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted - Analysis of the problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

Comment: @BeshalJaenal, You are welcome. I'm glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 3):

1. Do

   ```
   sudo dd if="/dev/zero" of="/dev/sdX" bs=4M count=32

   (X being the block device of the USB drive)
   ```
2. Reboot your computer. Explanation: no this shouldn't be necessary. Has it been necessary for me in the past for whatever stupid reason? Yes, it has. *shrug*
3. Use Gparted to create an `msdos` partition table on the USB drive, and then create a primary partition with whatever filesystem you like. (Psst. Don't forget to hit the <kbd>Apply</kbd> button)