# Insufficient storage space in Micro SD card although I utilized little of the space?

Tags: partitioning, android, gparted, sd-card

My MicroSD card has 16GB space, but I've only utilized 2.2GB of it (mainly transferring images). I used gparted to format the card to FAT32 since the original formatting may not be based on Ubuntu. But this error still persists. Is FAT32 the only system that is compatible with android? (especially since my card size is small). I tried ext4 as well but android doesn't detect this system at all.

Is the formatting by gparted sufficient?

Ubuntu version: 16.04 LTS

Screenshot of commands and output from gparted:
[image]

Error after deleting partition and reallocating the full memory:
[image]

Output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  9.6M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       219G  207G  1.4G 100% /
tmpfs           7.8G  449M  7.4G   6% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.6G   36K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/mmcblk0p1   15G  2.2G   13G  15% /media/kwotsin/E9B6-901C
```

Output of `sudo lsblk -f`:

```
NAME        FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                           
├─sda1      ext4         30b6609e-ee59-4220-a065-18856c9c1047 /
└─sda5      swap         268d1b29-e948-4da7-8b0f-79e26b334743 [SWAP]
mmcblk0                                                       
└─mmcblk0p1 vfat         E9B6-901C                            /media/kwotsin/E9B
```

Output of `sudo parted -ls`:

```
Model: SD SD16G (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 15.6GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  15.6GB  15.6GB  primary  fat32
```

Comment: which version of Ubuntu is using the MicroSD card?

Comment: I'm currently using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: What is the purpose of what you are trying to do? Is there any reason why don't you just format the entire MicroSD card to FAT32?

Comment: Did you create a partition and then created the FAT32 file system in that partition? Please edit your question and post the output of the following commands, when the micro SD card is connected and the partition is mounted, `df -h` ; `sudo lsblk -f` ; `sudo lsblk -m` ; `sudo parted -ls` The output of those commands can help us help you.

Comment: I can see from the temporary picture, that you created a partition and in that partition created a FAT32 file system. I think it looks like it should. But please add the output of the commands in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes I think I might have just formatted only the partition (the size starts with 3 instead of 1). I have just tried selecting the partition option, deleting the partition and reallocating it with the full capacity. But it seems the partition is still automatically the smaller one. Is this way of changing the partition correct?

Comment: According to the screenshot, the partition seems to be 14.50 GiB, which is way more than you say is available. I still want to see the output of those commands. After seeing the output, it may be possible to give better advice. As it is now, I can only suggest that you use another tool to create the partition and file system, **'restore to a standard storage device' with mkusb** according to this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/939230/formatting-a-usb-stick-unable-to-operate-usb/939266#939266

Comment: It is possible that the card is failing, that some memory cells are damaged and/or the built-in programs is damaged. See this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035

Comment: I thought the best way to test if the partition is really 14.50GB even after deleting it and reallocating it is to try the transfer again. But it gives me the same error like previously. I have attached the output of the commands you mentioned

Comment: As for the card failing, I thought so too. This is the second card I purchased, and both gave me the same problem. Could it be a system error instead?

Comment: `/dev/mmcblk0p1   15G  2.2G   13G  15% /media/kwotsin/E9B6-901C` looks like it should. There should be 13GiB available. Maybe the problem is that the drive is mounted read-only or without read access for your user ID (which can be fixed), or that the whole drive is read-only ('gridlocked', which is the first step in the failing process).

Comment: Try to use the first two gigabytes again - write some other files - will they survive after unmounting and unplugging? Let us continue in the automatically generated chat room :-)

Comment: For the read-only mounting, I think writing files is possible too since I can still create new folders and files in the card. As for read-access, I am the super user for this machine, so I don't think it's an access issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63597/discussion-between-sudodus-and-lee-kwot-sin).