# Ubuntu - USB drive fixing after interrupted formatting

Tags: usb, disk, fsck, testdrive

I have a problem with already 2nd USB drives, most probably due to the reason of choosing slow formatting option. Because it takes a LOT of time, I probably forget about it and accidentally break the formatting process. Now I have 2 completely useless USB drives.

Ubuntu can't read them, actually, Disks application recognize them, but there are very few options offered: "Edit Mount Options", "Eject" and "Power Off". Gparted doesn't recognize it, as well as testdrive and fsck ("No medium found while trying to open /dev/sdc").

[image]

I suppose that drivers for recognizing USB drive are corrupted or maybe there is some bad sector in an important part of the memory. I hope there is a way to make this 2 USB drives alive again.

---

I know how this will sound, but...I also break slow HDD partition formatting after 12 hours (accidentally), and I didn't have any problem. So there is my hope that it is possible to fix USB drives.

Comment: Try formatting the drives in Windows using the Disk Management app, create a GPT partition table, and a NTFS partition. Report back.

Comment: Disk Management app can't do anything with the USB drive, it just recognizes that it is USB and registers it as offline with 0 bytes.

Comment: It probably has more to do with the USB-to-SATA interface module then. Disassemble the drive enclosures, and remove the hard drive, and connect it directly to a SATA bus, try and quick format it to DOS, reassemble the drive enclosures, and retry to quick init it again. Report back.

Answer (score 1):

- If a hard disk drive,HDD, or solid state drive, SSD: Check the [S.M.A.R.T. information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972978/fsck-reports-that-filesystem-still-has-errors-what-should-i-do-now/972983?s=3|14.1938#972983) of the drive (to tell if there is something fundamentally wrong with the hardware).
- For all drives, mass storage devices including HDD, SSD, pendrive, memory card:

  1. Try with [mkusb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/939230/formatting-a-usb-stick-unable-to-operate-usb/939266#939266) to wipe the first mibibyte, and if successful, try again with `gparted` to create the partitions you want.
  2. If still problems, analyze them and try again to solve them according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035).

Comment: I tried almost all of the suggested actions, but unfortunately, nothing solves the problem. It is strange that also Windows recognizes the USB drive, but it can't read it.

Comment: @Gujche, I'm sorry, but it makes me think that the USB drive is damaged (physically).

Comment: I do not exclude that option (that nasty Ubuntu could do a lot of bad things), but before I start with autopsy I would like to try all possible options.

Comment: @Gujche, I wish you good luck, when you try also the remaining actions :-)