# Can't use my external USB drive?

Tags: usb, chromebook

So I am using Ubuntu Xenial on my Acer Chromebook, anyways, it seems I can't use my external USB drive as it states "unable to mount 31GB volume" "not authorized to preform action" I have no idea why this is happening, also I'm very very green in this area.

Comment: Did you use that flash drive as installer? Most installers use dd to create a hybrid DVD flash drive configuration that is not a standard partitioned drive. Reset USB flash that was dd'd to make it usable again
https://askubuntu.com/questions/939230/formatting-a-usb-stick-unable-to-operate-usb/939266#939266 & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive

Answer (score 0):

I had found a solution which is not the exact answer but an way around this problem. Actually in ubuntu 18.04  plug and play feature is (I guess) disabled; so the usb will show up in the ls command i.e.

```
ls /dev/sd* | grep sd
```

but will not be automatically mounted (except if if was present a boot time).

So solution is to mount is manually e.g. if the usb is detected at sdb1 then use this command

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb
```

FYI: i am assuming that there is a usb folder in mnt folder