# SSD shows wrong size

Tags: ssd

I've done some "magic" with my 500gb ssd (sda), which now shows only 1gb in size.
I've tried to find some ans on google, unfortunately I was not successful.
Any thoughts?

fdisk -l gives:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 3,7 MiB, 3846144 bytes, 7512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 143,5 MiB, 150470656 bytes, 293888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 91,1 MiB, 95522816 bytes, 186568 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 35,3 MiB, 37027840 bytes, 72320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 4 MiB, 4214784 bytes, 8232 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 1008 KiB, 1032192 bytes, 2016 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 14,5 MiB, 15208448 bytes, 29704 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 13 MiB, 13619200 bytes, 26600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 1023,8 MiB, 1073479680 bytes, 2096640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 59,6 GiB, 64023257088 bytes, 125045424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x15723551

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 125044735 125042688 59,6G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 58,7 GiB, 62973280256 bytes, 122994688 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 976 MiB, 1023410176 bytes, 1998848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4C0F550B-7BF1-1B49-91E0-0203376B02CD

Device                              Start     End Sectors  Size Type
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1-part1     1 1998847 1998847  976M EFI System


Disk /dev/loop8: 140,7 MiB, 147496960 bytes, 288080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 2,3 MiB, 2355200 bytes, 4600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 91 MiB, 95408128 bytes, 186344 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 14,8 MiB, 15458304 bytes, 30192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 140,7 MiB, 147496960 bytes, 288080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 3,7 MiB, 3878912 bytes, 7576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop14: 53,7 MiB, 56315904 bytes, 109992 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop15: 34,6 MiB, 36216832 bytes, 70736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

sudo parted -l:

```
Error: /dev/sda: unrecognised disk label
Model: ATA SM2258AB-10-0083 (scsi)                                        
Disk /dev/sda: 1073MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 

Model: ATA M4-CT064M4SSD2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 64,0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  64,0GB  64,0GB  primary               boot, lvm


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 1023MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      512B   1023MB  1023MB                     boot, esp


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 63,0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0,00B  63,0GB  63,0GB  ext4
```

[GParted PS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDdx0.png)
[GParted PS2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MADdT.png)

Many thanks.
J

Comment: "... A magician never reveals his secrets.." Either tell us what "magic you did" or ask Penn and Teller

Comment: I would gladly tell you if I knew :) 500gb was my primary OS, when I decided I would have dedicated SSD 60gb for OS. When I installed it, I couldnt access my 500gb. In the process of fixing it, I made my "magic" :)

Comment: Again, tell us what you did, or you're on you onw

Comment: Sorry I can be more helpful. Thank you for taking time and reading my question.

Answer (score 2):

No, its not. A 500GB SSD should have CHS 608xx 255 63, so testdisk "sees" only the
damaged partition table. 
You need to boot from live- or gparted- or any rescue-stick, because partition manipulation only works with unmountet ssd. Open gparted -> drives -> new partition table. If that don't works you have to delete all existing partitions first and then new table.

Comment: Unfortunately creating partition table does not change anything. Deleting or any other command is not available (gray menu)(Ive added new PS. Please see "GParted PS2" in my post).

Comment: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=512 count=1 conv=notrunc` where `sdx` is replaced with the drive's ID (not `sdb1`, for example, but something like `sdb`, not ending in a number (which means it only applies to a partition)).

Potential answer from https://serverfault.com/questions/250839/deleting-all-partitions-from-the-command-line

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it didnt work. After dd, Ive rebooted and it still shows 1gb disk size. Tried also looking for potential answer in link you provided. No luck.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

sda has an unknown partition table "Partition Table: unknown".
Use gparded or any other partioning tool to set either msdos or gpt table.

Comment: I've tried with gparted (msdos and gpt), but nothing has changed.

Comment: I've tried to do some analysis with testdisk. Do you think CHS 130 255 63 is ok?

Comment: Did you either intentionally or accidentally use it as an installer? That converts it to a hybrid DVD/Flash drive configuration with no readable partition table. You then have to zero the beginning of the drive so a new partition table can be created. Reset USB flash that was dd'd to make it usable again
https://askubuntu.com/questions/939230/formatting-a-usb-stick-unable-to-operate-usb/939266#939266 & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive very careful on using dd to clear beginning of drive. Double & triple check that correct drive is used.

Comment: I dont think so. For the installation I used my usb drive (currently running live). Ive installed and tried with dd (wipe first MB). Operations was successfully done, but nothing changed in gparted (cannot create partition table). Any thoughts?