# Can not write to usb stick after formatting

Tags: permissions, usb-drive

I tried with Disks, and GParted with no luck.

Formatted to fat32, the owner is root, and the permissions are none for group root.

it was formated for xubuntu startup disk before.

[image]

Comment: Use `GParted` or `Disks` and delete all partitions on the USB stick then create one partition and format it.

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky,find a solution.

Comment: You may need to zero out beginning of drive. Reset USB flash that was dd'd to make it usable again
https://askubuntu.com/questions/939230/formatting-a-usb-stick-unable-to-operate-usb/939266#939266 & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive