# Rufus won't create bootable USB stick

Tags: boot, dual-boot, rufus

Every time I use Rufus to try to build a bootable USB stick, it says OK until I hit start, no matter what I try.

I tried changing USB sticks and finagling with permissions.  Many of the "how to fix this problem" posts online are from older versions of Windows, that don't match the current choices.

Then I immediately get this error:

```
Error: Access to the device is denied
```

Comment: can you access it from another application? or is it only rufus

Comment: Highly relevant: https://superuser.com/a/1538785. Some Windows applications block Rufus fro accessing the USB stick.

Comment: Which version of 1. Windows, 2. Rufus and 3. Ubuntu iso file are you trying to use? And which brand names and models of USB drive did you try?

Comment: If you previously used flash drive in hybrid DVD/flash mode created by dd or many tools then it may need start of drive erased. Reset USB flash that was dd'd to make it usable again, reuse
https://askubuntu.com/questions/939230/formatting-a-usb-stick-unable-to-operate-usb/939266#939266 & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive

Comment: Here's [a common mistake](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues/459) some users make that results in the error.

Comment: you could try balena etcher

Answer (score 1):

Look for an error in your Rufus error message that says:

```
ABORTED: Cannot use an image that is located on the target drive!

The iso you are trying to use resides on the same drive as the one you are trying  
to format. You are trying to saw the branch you're sitting on - what you are trying   
to do was never going to work in the first place!

Please move your iso to a different drive than your USB, and be mindful that ALL    
data on your USB drive will be erased.
```

If you got this error message do what the error message says and move the .iso file to anywhere in your home directory.

Comment: Not the error I'm getting.

Comment: @eSurfsnake, Please tell us more about the error output and about your hardware. Otherwise we can only guess, and not really help  you.

Comment: The hardware is a Dell 64 bit ARM architecture. It has its disk and I am trying ti make and then get the boot systems to launch 18.04.5 from a USB drive written with Ubuntu's own boot disk creator.

Comment: @eSurfsnake, I can find [arm iso files until 18.04.4 LTS](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.1/) but not 18.04.5. Where did you find it? Or were you trying an amd64 iso file?