# Unable to mount my usb pendrive or make into a bootable drive

Tags: boot, usb, mount, windows, fat32

I have a 8GB pendrive which is blank as far as I know.
I plug it in but it does not mount automatically.
I can see it in Disks Utility as well as with lsblk but not with the Files Manager.
I tried the instructions at: https://fossbytes.com/mount-unmount-usb-drive-on-ubuntu-linux/
However, I am not able to mount it as either the FAT32 or NFTS method.
After I created the dir on the desktop to serve as the mountpoint, running
sudo mount /dev/sdb /Desktop/extHD         returns
mount:  /Desktop/extHD: mount point does not exist.

Using the NTFS, predictably says that the NTFS signature is missing  with a bunch of other verbiage.

My goal is to create a bootable USB with Windows on it.
I have the ISO and am getting confused as to how to mount let alone create a bootable USB pendrive.
Please advise.  Thanks.

Comment: You can use Disks to format it.

Comment: You normally do not mount a drive, but the partition or sda1. If it does not have partitions, was it used as a installer created by dd? That is a hybrid/flash drive configuration and does not have partitions. Often then you have to zero out MBR, so you can then create partitions. Reset USB flash that was dd'd to make it usable again, reuse
https://askubuntu.com/questions/939230/formatting-a-usb-stick-unable-to-operate-usb/939266#939266 & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive

Answer (score 0):

There's a mistake on the mountpoint path. Instead of `/Desktop/extHD` it should be `/home/yourusername/Desktop/extHD`, or simply `./extHD` if you're already inside the Desktop folder. To find out where you are you can run the `pwd` command.

Provided you already have an iso, you can use [Etcher](https://www.etcher.net) or [mintstick](https://github.com/linuxmint/mintstick) to help you make bootable pendrives from iso files. If your iso is faulty, the most popular method I found for making one is by using WinToUSB.