# Erasing Ubuntu image on external hard-drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive, disk-image

I have burned an ubuntu image on an external hard-drive and I am trying to erase it. I have first tried to erase the image through the [pi-imager](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/) but for some reason I get the error:

```
Error formatting (through udisks2)
```

So then I mounted it, but for some reason it can only be mounted in "read-only" mode. My first question here is: how could I force the mount of my hard-drive to be in "write" mode ? After a few research I have decided to follow this [post](https://linuxhint.com/completely_wipe_hard_drive_ubuntu/) and compute:

```
wipe -q /dev/sdc2
```

It took hours to have the task complete, however the Ubuntu image is still on the hard-drive. So what am I doing wrong here such that the wipe doesn't work ?

The output of lsblk is :

```
...
sdc           8:32   0   3.7T  0 disk 
└─sdc2        8:34   0   1.5T  0 part 
nvme0n1     259:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
...
```

Could it be because I did `wipe -q /dev/sdc2` and not `wipe -q /dev/sdc` ? Please let me know if I could add additional information to my question as I don't see any other explanation tracks. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Did you use dd or a tools that used dd? You just need to erase partition table. Reset USB flash that was dd'd to make it usable again, reuse
https://askubuntu.com/questions/939230/formatting-a-usb-stick-unable-to-operate-usb/939266#939266 & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive & 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216152/usb-disk-read-only-cannot-format-turn-off-write-protection

Comment: Do: `sudo mount  -o remount,rw /dev/sda`. If failure, `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"`. You cannot wipe, write, or otherwise modify a Read Only `ro` disk.