# NAND USB2DISK (0.00) No media

Tags: partitioning, mount, usb-drive

when I tried to install ISO on pen-drive, it didn't complete and when i remount it , it no mounting when i search it in gnome disk it is showing NAND USB2DISK (0.00) no media . when i searched for solution they recommend to type

sudo disk -l
in terminal but my disk not showing there .
please help it is new  pen-drive and i want to use it back ,no care of data inside

Comment: Reuse dded image drive
Reset USB flash that was dd'd to make it usable again, reuse
https://askubuntu.com/questions/939230/formatting-a-usb-stick-unable-to-operate-usb/939266#939266 & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive & 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216152/usb-disk-read-only-cannot-format-turn-off-write-protection