Cannot access/mount USB drive despite showing up in Disks
My USB became unusable recently and I'm trying to fix it. I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 but the problem persists on older Ubuntu and Windows OS as well.
The symptoms:
Upon plugging it in, the computer makes a sound and the device shows up in the dmesg list:
[503371.231982] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 60 using xhci_hcd
[503371.363541] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000, bcdDevice=11.00
[503371.363553] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[503371.363556] usb 3-4: Product: Intenso Ultra Line
[503371.363560] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: SMI Technology
[503371.363562] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: 18010500003539
[503371.366805] usb-storage 3-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[503371.367071] scsi host0: usb-storage 3-4:1.0

Similarly, I can see it in Disks, from here I can see that device is assigned /dev/sda. However, I cannot see, e.g. the Size and the only option that I have here for configuring its settings is Edit Mount Options.

But I cannot access the drive via command line nor file manager. I tried the obvious (different ports, machines, OS, made sure that the ports are working with other drives, etc.) and of course mounting via sudo mount /dev/sda /media/usb/
Here I get the error: mount: /media/usb: no medium found on /dev/sda.
Formatting the drive to set it back to working conditions is also an option but how can I do this when access is restricted?
I'm starting to think that the device might be physically damaged but if someone here has any further ideas, they are much appreciated, thanks!

All USB drives eventually fail and must be replaced. Seems yours has reached that point.

Was it used as an installer & is hybrid DVD/flash drive which does not have partitions? Reset USB flash that was dd'd to make it usable again, reuse
https://askubuntu.com/questions/939230/formatting-a-usb-stick-unable-to-operate-usb/939266#939266 &
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive &
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216152/usb-disk-read-only-cannot-format-turn-off-write-protection

No, I used it as a regular flash drive for data transfer.

Try the following:
plug in the USB
Open a terminal.
Run in it:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall gparted
sudo gparted

From Gparted select your USB.
Unmount it if it is mounted.
Create a new gpt partition table
Create a partition in the free space, ext4 system
Apply the changes.
Close Gparted
Close the terminal
Try to access the USB

Thanks for your response @kyodake.
The device is not showing up in gparted unfortunately.

Then, unfortunately, you will have to discard it, its time of use has ended.

It may be possible to salvage it. You will need an adapter to plug the USB into your smart-phone. I've done this and it actually worked several times when trying to format a USB that has a partition that can't be over-written with the standard formatting in Nautilus or Disks. Just plug the USB into the adapter and then the adapter into the phone and you should get a notification of a new USB device is plugged-in. At this point you should be able to format the USB. If it's salvageable, that should do it. If not, it's likely a "block" and should be retired.
