Ubuntu 24.04 LTS manual partition of disk doesn't see all USB drives
I am trying to install a portable Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on a USB drive but when i choose manual partitioning my target USB drive is not shown although the LSBLK command shows my drive unmounted.  Earlier, I installed Ubuntu 24.04 on a USB drive, but I chose then "erase everything".  I tried different USB drives to no avail.
Thank you....ernesto
here is the data requested; the drive in question is the /dev/sdi  Thank you!
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.63 GiB, 1752752128 bytes, 3423344 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop1: 471.01 MiB, 493887488 bytes, 964624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop2: 874.37 MiB, 916840448 bytes, 1790704 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop3: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop4: 74.27 MiB, 77881344 bytes, 152112 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop5: 505.09 MiB, 529625088 bytes, 1034424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop6: 10.72 MiB, 11239424 bytes, 21952 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop7: 269.77 MiB, 282873856 bytes, 552488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: ST2000DM001-1CH1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D727576F-C8CF-49F9-B0F9-FDF19C5AC4E5
Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 3907028991 3907026944  1.8T Linux filesystem
Disk /dev/sdb: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG SSD PM83
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5B5C1DC6-A24E-4368-B118-A9570A9B2AFC
Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048   2203647   2201600     1G EFI System
/dev/sdb2  2203648 500115455 497911808 237.4G Linux filesystem
Disk /dev/sdc: 14.55 TiB, 16000900660736 bytes, 31251759103 sectors
Disk model: Expansion HDD
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2F2EE02D-D540-43FF-B2E7-5751A0C3FE48
Device           Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1         2048 23437500415 23437498368 10.9T Linux filesystem
/dev/sdc2  23437500416 31251757055  7814256640  3.6T Microsoft basic data
Disk /dev/sdd: 29.89 GiB, 32094814208 bytes, 62685184 sectors
Disk model: USB 2.0 FD
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x12fc16ad
Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1  *     2048 62685151 62683104 29.9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
Disk /dev/loop8: 10.54 MiB, 11051008 bytes, 21584 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop9: 91.69 MiB, 96141312 bytes, 187776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop10: 500 KiB, 512000 bytes, 1000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop11: 38.83 MiB, 40714240 bytes, 79520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop12: 149.63 MiB, 156901376 bytes, 306448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/loop13: 116.78 MiB, 122449920 bytes, 239160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/sdi: 464.38 GiB, 498629345280 bytes, 973885440 sectors
Disk model: USB
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo inxi -F
System:
Host: ubuntu Kernel: 6.8.0-41-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
Desktop: GNOME v: 46.0 Distro: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)
Machine:
Type: Desktop System: Dell product: XPS 8500 v: N/A serial: DCWVDX1
Mobo: Dell model: 0NW73C v: A01 serial: ..CN7220033H00OP. UEFI: Dell
v: A14 date: 06/25/2018
CPU:
Info: quad core model: Intel Core i7-3770 bits: 64 type: MT MCP cache:
L2: 1024 KiB
Speed (MHz): avg: 1599 min/max: 1600/3900 cores: 1: 1600 2: 1600 3: 1600
4: 1600 5: 1600 6: 1600 7: 1596 8: 1600
Graphics:
Device-1: NVIDIA GK104 [GeForce GTX 660 OEM] driver: N/A
Display: server: X.Org v: 21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6 driver: X:
loaded: modesetting,nouveau,vesa unloaded: fbdev dri: swrast gpu: N/A
resolution: 1024x768~60Hz
API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: kms_swrast,swrast
platforms: gbm,x11,surfaceless,device
API: OpenGL v: 4.5 vendor: mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.1 renderer: llvmpipe
(LLVM 17.0.6 256 bits)
Audio:
Device-1: Intel 7 Series/C216 Family High Definition Audio
driver: snd_hda_intel
Device-2: NVIDIA GK104 HDMI Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
Device-3: Creative Labs CA0132 Sound Core3D [Sound Blaster Recon3D /
Z-Series BlasterX AE-5 Plus] driver: snd_hda_intel
API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-41-generic status: kernel-api
Network:
Device-1: Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2230 driver: iwlwifi
IF: wlp2s0 state: down mac: 68:17:29:11:fe:3b
Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
driver: r8169
IF: enp3s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: b8:ca:3a:7c:83:13
Bluetooth:
Device-1: Microsoft Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
driver: hid-generic,usbhid type: USB
Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 state: up address: 68:17:29:11:FE:3F bt-v: 4.0
Device-2: Intel Centrino Bluetooth Wireless Transceiver driver: btusb
type: USB
Drives:
Local Storage: total: 17.09 TiB used: 5.79 GiB (0.0%)
ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST2000DM001-1CH164 size: 1.82 TiB
ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Samsung model: SSD PM830 mSATA 256GB
size: 238.47 GiB
ID-3: /dev/sdc vendor: Seagate model: Expansion HDD size: 14.55 TiB
type: USB
ID-4: /dev/sdd vendor: PNY model: USB 2.0 FD size: 29.89 GiB type: USB
ID-5: /dev/sdi vendor: ASolid model: USB size: 464.38 GiB type: USB
Partition:
ID-1: / size: 11.72 GiB used: 251.3 MiB (2.1%) fs: overlay source: ERR-102
Swap:
Alert: No swap data was found.
Sensors:
System Temperatures: cpu: 13.0 C mobo: N/A
Fan Speeds (rpm): cpu: 884 mobo: 920
Info:
Memory: total: 24 GiB available: 23.43 GiB used: 2.61 GiB (11.1%)
Processes: 303 Uptime: 24m Shell: Sudo inxi: 3.3.34

Do you mean 24.04, there is not 24.02? Was USB drive used as installer? You may need to erase partition table area a many installers uses dd and create a hybrid DVD/flash drive. https://askubuntu.com/questions/939230/formatting-a-usb-stick-unable-to-operate-usb/939266#939266 &
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive &
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216152/usb-disk-read-only-cannot-format-turn-off-write-protection  Do gparted on live installer see drive?

In a Live Ubuntu session open a terminal and run: sudo fdisk -l , sudo inxi -F, edit your post copy and paste the outputs into it.

On which of these disks do you want to install Ubuntu: /dev/sda Seagate 1.82 TiB. /dev/sdb Samsung SSD 238.47 GiB. /dev/sdc Seagate 14.55 TiB USB. /dev/sdd PNY 29.89 GiB USB. /dev/sdi Asólid USB 464.38 GiB. And which is the USB that contains the Ubuntu iso.

/dev/sdd PNY 29.89 GiB USB is the Ubuntu ISO; /dev/sdi Asólid USB 464.38 GiB is where I would like to install Ubuntu.  Thank you for your patience
